# use ng-repeat with selected value from drop-down

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

i am trying to repeat table when value from drop down is selected.

The drop-down is in the table.
Here is my code html

```html
<div class="table-container" ng-repeat="eachVehicleType in schemeInfo.vehicleTypeSchemeList">
  <div class="table-responsive" style="width: 65%;">
<table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered table-advanced tablesorter">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Vehicle Type</th>
    <th>Scheme Amount</th>
    <th>Scheme Percentage</th>
    <th>From Distance</th>
    <th>To Distance</th>

  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <md-input-container flex>
        <select ng-model="schemeInfo.vehicleType" ng-change="addVehicleTypeTable() "
                class="form-control select-bottom" style="margin-top: 24px;">
          <option value="">Vehicle Type</option>
          <option value="THREE_WHEELER_OPEN">THREE WHEELER</option>
          <option value="PICK_UP_OPEN">PICK UP</option>
          <option value="MINI_TRUCK_OPEN">MINI TRUCK</option>
        </select></md-input-container>
    </td>

    <td style="padding-top: 31px;padding-left: 19px;"><input style="width: 83px;" ng-model="schemeInfo.schemeAmount"
                                                             type="text" maxlength="4" minlength="1"
                                                             class=" form-control required" required
                                                             ng-pattern="/^[0-9]$/"/></td>

    <td style="padding-top: 31px;padding-left: 19px;"><input style="width: 83px;"
                                                             ng-model="schemeInfo.schemePercentage" type="text"
                                                             maxlength="4" minlength="1"
                                                             class=" form-control required" required
                                                             ng-pattern="/^[0-9]$/"/></td>

    <td style="padding-top: 31px;padding-left: 19px;"><input style="width: 83px;" ng-model="schemeInfo.fromDistance"
                                                             type="text" name="captivereverseBidPrice" maxlength="4"
                                                             minlength="1"
                                                             class=" form-control required" required
                                                             ng-pattern="/^[0-9]$/"/></td>

    <td style="padding-top: 31px;padding-left: 19px;"><input style="width: 83px;" ng-model="schemeInfo.toDistance"
                                                             type="text" maxlength="4" minlength="1"
                                                             class=" form-control required" required
                                                             ng-pattern="/^[0-9]$/"/></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
  </div>
</div>
```

view is as follows
[image]

i want when i choose different value from drop-down table should be repeat.

Comment: You could try to make an object for your form with a list of objects and if the value from the dropdown changes, add a new object to the list. Then you user ng-repeat on your <tr> or <table> or whereever you want and it should repeat your table everytime something changed.

Comment: now i am able to repeat the table but he value to list in table change in all repeated tables.....i mean i am repeating the table when i choose different elements from drop-down and i am setting the current drop-down value to  one of the column of table.
But when table repeats the current drop down value set to all tables.
Please help me wit that

Comment: it would be very helpful, if you would provide us the code of your controller, we may be able to help you a little bit better with that